# convert elements of datatable into a byte array (or a list of(byte))

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I'm looking at the best way to create a byte array or List of(`byte`) for elements in a datatable, now I write out the data into a file in binary
format as follows:

```
dim fs as filestream("test.dat")
dim writebinary as binarywriter(fs)
for each dRow as datarow in DT.rows
    writebinary.write(dRow(0))  'int32
    writebinary.write(dRow(1))  'double
    writebinary.write(dRow(3))  'long
next
fs.close
writebinary.dispose
```

what I would like is to write the data into a byte array or list something like:

```
'dim bArray() as byte                 ' this way
dim bList as List of(byte)           ' or this way
for each dRow as DataRow in DT.rows
    blist.add(bitconverter.getbytes(dRow(0)))
    blist.add(bitconverter.getbytes(dRow(1)))
    blist.add(bitconverter.getbytes(dRow(3)))
next
```

'then do some tests on blist  (or `bArray`) to determine if I should save the data

```
if bSuccessful then
   dim fs as filestream("test.dat")
   dim writebinary as binarywriter(fs)
   for each bValue as byte in blist
       writebinary.write(bvalue)  
   next
   fs.close
   writebinary.dispose
endif
```

Of course the line

```
blist.add(bitconverter.getbytes(dRow(0)))
```

is wrong and doesn't work. 
The first set of code does work, the `2` following sets of code are what I'm asking advice on how to do. Of course, I don't know how many bytes I will need initially and is thus the reason I thought to use a List of(`Byte`).

Comment: Instead of creating a `FileStream`, create a `MemoryStream`.  You then use the `BinaryWriter` in exactly the same way.  It will work with any type of `Stream`.  Once you're done writing, call `ToArray` to get the stream contents as a `Byte` array.  If you then want to write that to a file, call `File.WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: By the way, you should use a `Using` statement to create objects that will be closed/disposed in the same context.  The object will then be closed/disposed implicitly at the `End Using` statement, even if an exception is thrown and not caught within the block.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`.  The last thing you want when trying to write out the binary representation of primitive types is for the compiler to guess the data type and do an implicit conversion. `dRow(0)` is an `Object` type that contains an `Int32`.  Since you now the data type, apply the proper casting (`CInt(dRow(0))`) before writing it to the stream so that the proper write method is used.